# Share same Pandas Dataframe between process Pool without copying again and again

Tags: python, pandas, multiprocessing

I have a dataframe which holds a query result for about 1 million or more

When i pass this to map function which performs comparison of two dataframes , the above mentioned dataframe gets copied for every process and gives me memory error.

Sample code

```
df = pd.read_sql_query('Query returning 1 million or more rows')

def comparison(df):
   
# Having comparison logic which uses the df object mentioned above

p = Pool(2)
fn = partial(comparison,df)
p.map(fn,'some iterator')
```

now what i want is on mapping comparison function to different processes , it shoul not copy the df again and again

I have tried moving the query fetching part i.e the df inside the compariosn function ,
it works but gets executed again and again for each iterator object , since the query takes 40 - 50 seconds to execute , this is a time overhead everytime . Therfore i only wat to do it once and use it everytime

Comment: Which platform is this on? If the df is a global(-ish) variable and you're on Linux or macOS, it should use copy-on-write semantics.

Comment: @AKX i am on Windows and this df object is in main function

Comment: Could you try to initialize all the 3 dataframes once and let me know what is the result.(Don t run your function). If the 3 dataframe works properly, that means there are things to do. If it doesn't, you have to downgrade your process count.

Comment: @anlgrses Sorry i di not get our point , there are not 3 dataframes , i nitialize the dataframe only once. before spinning any process. when i pass the initialized df to map function , it copies it again and again for difeerent processes

Comment: Are you comparing dataframe with the rows inside or with another dataframe(Also your function takes 1 parameter but you gave 2 parameters)? It should be clarified

Comment: Honestly, though – do your comparison in the database and don't return a million rows to handle in Python.

Comment: @anlgrses yes, the 'some iterator ' part is a second dataframe iterator object against which comparison of df object is done using pandas apply function

Answer (score 2):

> i am on Windows and this df object is in main function

Then you're out of luck.

Since there isn't copy-on-write memory on Windows, you can't share a Python variable transparently between multiple processes without copying occurring.

([Copy-on-write mmaps do exist](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/memory/creating-named-shared-memory?redirectedfrom=MSDN) but they can't be the backing memory for dfs to the best of my knowledge.)